# Experimenting with a key bind script in a game, but i get an error. When I fix the error it gives me the same error

Tags: notepad++

My script is as follows:

```
bind; o "buy ak47; buy m4a1_silencer;";
```

And when I run the script I get the error:

```
buttons.nut line = (1) column = (38) : error end of statement expected (;  or lf)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error if I have the ";" at the end of the line in the 38th column as it says. What am I doing wrong, am I blind?

Comment: Is "Notepad++" the name of your game?

Comment: That's the weirdest question I've seen on SO so far.

Comment: Lol, the game is Counterstrike, but yes I'm making the script in Notepad++.

Comment: and it's written in the Squirrel scripting language?

Comment: AKAIK, Valve(the company who made the game) just gave some functions some names, and used it in the console. If I type the whole 'bind' command into the console, it works, but when I use it in N++ it tells me it expects the ';' at the end even though it's already there.